# Kafka partition leader not updated after broker removed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, devops, marathon

I have Kafka cluster managed by marathon/mesos which had 3 brokers version `0.10.2.1`. The docker images are based on [wurstmeister/kafka-docker](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker). The `broker.id=-1` which is assigned automatically and sequentially at start up and leaders are auto-rebalanced `auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true`. Clients are version `0.8.2.1`.

Zookeeper configuration:

```sh
➜ zkCli -server zookeeper.example.com:2181 ls /brokers/ids
[1106, 1105, 1104]

➜ zkCli -server zookeeper.example.com:2181 get /brokers/ids/1104
{"listener_security_protocol_map":{"PLAINTEXT":"PLAINTEXT"},
"endpoints":["PLAINTEXT://host1.mesos-slave.example.com:9092"],
"jmx_port":9999,"host":"host1.mesos-slave.example.com",
"timestamp":"1500987386409",
"port":9092,"version":4}

➜ zkCli -server zookeeper.example.com:2181 get /brokers/ids/1105
{"listener_security_protocol_map":{"PLAINTEXT":"PLAINTEXT"},
"endpoints":["PLAINTEXT://host2.mesos-slave.example.com:9092"],
"jmx_port":9999,"host":"host2.mesos-slave.example.com",
"timestamp":"1500987390304",
"port":9092,"version":4}

➜ zkCli -server zookeeper.example.com:2181 get /brokers/ids/1106
{"listener_security_protocol_map":{"PLAINTEXT":"PLAINTEXT"},
"endpoints":["PLAINTEXT://host3.mesos-slave.example.com:9092"],
"jmx_port":9999,"host":"host3.mesos-slave.example.com",
"timestamp":"1500987390447","port":9092,"version":4}

➜ bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeper.example.com:2181 --create --topic test-topic --partitions 2 --replication-factor 2
Created topic "test-topic".

➜ bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeper.example.com:2181 --describe --topic test-topic
Topic:test-topic    PartitionCount:2        ReplicationFactor:2     Configs:
        Topic: test-topic  Partition: 0    Leader: 1106    Replicas: 1106,1104     Isr: 1106
        Topic: test-topic  Partition: 1    Leader: 1105    Replicas: 1104,1105     Isr: 1105
```

Consumers can consume what producers are outputting.

```sh
➜ /opt/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1 bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 10.0.1.3:9092,10.0.1.1:9092 --topic test-topic
[2017-07-25 12:57:17,760] WARN Property topic is not valid (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3
...

➜ /opt/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1 bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper zookeeper.example.com:2181 --topic test-topic --from-beginning
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3
...
```

Then broker 1104 and 1105 (host1 and host2) go out and another one is coming online, 1107 (host 1), manually using marathon interface

```sh
➜ zkCli -server zookeeper.example.com:2181 ls /brokers/ids
[1107, 1106]

➜ zkCli -server zookeeper.example.com:2181 get /brokers/ids/1107
{"listener_security_protocol_map":{"PLAINTEXT":"PLAINTEXT"},
"endpoints":["PLAINTEXT://host1.mesos-slave.example.com:9092"],
"jmx_port":9999,"host":"host1.mesos-slave.example.com",
"timestamp":"1500991298225","port":9092,"version":4}
```

Consumer still gets messages from the producer but the topics description looks out of date:

```sh
Topic:test-topic    PartitionCount:2        ReplicationFactor:2     Configs:
        Topic: test-topic  Partition: 0    Leader: 1106    Replicas: 1106,1104     Isr: 1106
        Topic: test-topic  Partition: 1    Leader: 1105    Replicas: 1104,1105     Isr: 1105
```

I tried rebalancing the `kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh`, `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh`.

```sh
➜ $cat all_partitions.json
{
  "version":1,
  "partitions":[
    {"topic":"test-topic","partition":0,"replicas":[1106,1107]},
    {"topic":"test-topic","partition":1,"replicas":[1107,1106]}
  ]
}

➜ bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper zookeeper.example.com:2181 --reassignment-json-file all_partitions.json --execute

➜ bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper zookeeper.example.com:2181 --reassignment-json-file all_partitions.json --verify

Status of partition reassignment:
Reassignment of partition [test-topic,0] completed successfully
Reassignment of partition [test-topic,1] is still in progress

➜ $cat all_leaders.json
{
  "partitions":[
    {"topic": "test-topic", "partition": 0},
    {"topic": "test-topic", "partition": 1}
  ]
}

➜ bin/kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh --zookeeper zookeeper.example.com:2181 --path-to-json-file all_leaders.json
Created preferred replica election path with {"version":1,"partitions":[{"topic":"test-topic","partition":0},{"topic":"test-topic","partition":1}]}
Successfully started preferred replica election for partitions Set([test-topic,0], [test-topic,1])
```

The partition leader for partitions 1 is still 1105 which doesn't make any sense:

```sh
➜ bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeper.example.com:2181 --describe --topic test-topic

Topic:test-topic    PartitionCount:2        ReplicationFactor:2     Configs:
        Topic: test-topic   Partition: 0    Leader: 1106    Replicas: 1106,1107     Isr: 1106,1107
        Topic: test-topic   Partition: 1    Leader: 1105    Replicas: 1107,1106,1104,1105   Isr: 1105
```

Why partition 1 thinks that leader is still 1105 although host2 is not alive?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar issue with Apache kafka 2.11. Have a cluster of 3 brokers, with topic of partitions = 2 and replication factor = 1. So, my topic's partitions were spread across 2 brokers out of 3.In the midst of producing messages, I manually shut down one of the brokers where one of the partition resided.After considerable time had passed, the leader of the aforesaid partition continued to be shown as -1. ie the partition did not get shifted to the 3rd active and running broker. I had `auto.leader.rebalance.enable` set to true on all brokers. Also, the Producer client kept on trying to produce to the partition that was on the shut doen broker, and continued failing to produce.